# Controlling modifier key behavior via the terminal on mac

Tags: macos

Most of the time, I like the "caps lock" to be mapped to the control key.  Sometimes, I want it to be bound to "caps lock".  I want to switch it in a shell script, so I can do it automatically or via a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences*.plist`, but I don't know any way to apply changes to it without logging out and back in. KeyRemap4MacBook has a [command line utility](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document-misc.html.en) that allows disabling and enabling settings, but it doesn't work with PCKeyboardHack.

This only changes the settings for one keyboard and doesn't work if the system language is not English.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    click button 1 of tab group 1
    tell sheet 1
        tell pop up button 4
            click
            delay 0.1
            if value is "⇪ Caps Lock" then
                click menu item 2 of menu 1
            else
                click menu item 1 of menu 1
            end if
        end tell
        click button "OK"
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```